# Extract username from forward slash separated text

Tags: regex, data-extraction

I need to extract a username from the log below via regex for a log collector.

Due to the nature of the logs we're getting its not possible to define exactly how many forward slashes are going to be available and I need to select a specific piece of data, as there are multiple occurances of similar formatted data.

Required data:

```
name="performedby" label="Performed By" value="blah.com/blah/blah blah/blah/**USERNAME**"|
```

<46>Jun 23 10:38:49 10.51.200.76 25113 LOGbinder EX|3.1|success|2016-06-23T10:38:49.0000000-05:00|Add-MailboxPermission Exchange cmdlet issued|name="occurred" label="Occurred" value="6/23/2016 10:38:49 AM"|name="cmdlet" label="Cmdlet" value="Add-MailboxPermission"|name="performedby" label="Performed By" value="blah.com/blah/blah blah/blah/**USERNAME**"|name="succeeded" label="Succeeded" value="Yes"|name="error" label="Error" value="None"|name="originatingserver label="Originating Server" value="black"|name="objectmodified" label="Object Modified" value="blah/blah/USERNAME"|name="parameters" label="Parameters" value="Name: Identity, Value: [blah]Name: User, Value: [blah/blah]Name AccessRights, Value: [FullAccess]Name: InheritanceType, Value: [All]"|name="properties" label="Modified Properties" value="n/a"|name="additionalinfo" label="Additional Information"

I've tried a few different regex commands but I'm not able to extract the necessary information without exactly stating how many / there will be.

```
blah\.com[.*\/](.*?)"\|name
```

Comment: *a username* - just one? What signifies a username? Are all the last words in `value` with forward slashes usernames?

Comment: username is typically a full name i.e. "john smith" etc.

Comment: check my updated answer

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
blah\.com.*\/(.*?)"\|
```

Check [here](https://regex101.com/r/vE2cT4/2)

If your username format is this :

```
value="abc.xyz/something/something/..../USERNAME"
```

then use this :

```
\..*\/(.*?)"
```

check [here](https://regex101.com/r/gO1xG7/2)

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution:
`value="[a-z\.\/]*\/(.*)"`

(The first capture group is the username)

Working example:
https://regex101.com/r/qZ0zC8/2

Comment: This also matches other strings and it is not clear if the first "value" will be username.

Comment: Use the first capture group, this solution does not specify the domain name thus leaving you the option of extracting the username from multiple domains.

Comment: I added another possible solution, if the username is a less than 2 characters long it won't capture: https://regex101.com/r/qZ0zC8/3

Comment: The third version is better.

Answer (score 0):

Mayby like this?

```
blah.(\w+\/)+\K([\w]+)
```

It's catch Username but since it's between ** so I also match them

tested in notepad++

Comment: Hi the ** is just bold on here to highlight the username (not my addtion but the text editor.  Original is: <46>Jun 23 10:38:49 10.51.200.76 25113 LOGbinder EX|3.1|success|2016-06-23T10:38:49.0000000-05:00|Add-MailboxPermission Exchange cmdlet issued|name="occurred" label="Occurred" value="6/23/2016 10:38:49 AM"|name="cmdlet" label="Cmdlet" value="Add-MailboxPermission"|name="performedby" label="Performed By" value="blah.com/blah/blah blah/blah/USERNAME"|name="succeeded" label="Succeeded" value="Yes"|name="error" label="Error" value="None"|name="originatingserver label="Originating Server"

Comment: Edit's been made in the regex above.